# Java GridBagLayout Defaults Top Left on Compilation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am using the WindowBuilder in Eclipse to design a GUI. The panel with username and password has a gridbaglayout. This is how I have the set up of the components in the design section of the WindowBuilder:

[image: See image of GUI in the window builder]

But this is how it shows when I actually run and compile the code:

[image: See image when compiled here]

Code generated:

```
JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 170);
        contentPane.add(panelTop);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelTop = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelTop.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0};
        gbl_panelTop.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panelTop.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelTop.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelTop.setLayout(gbl_panelTop);
        
        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblUsername = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblUsername.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblUsername.gridx = 2;
        gbc_lblUsername.gridy = 2;
        panelTop.add(lblUsername, gbc_lblUsername);
        
        txtUsername = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_txtUsername = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_txtUsername.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_txtUsername.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_txtUsername.gridx = 4;
        gbc_txtUsername.gridy = 2;
        panelTop.add(txtUsername, gbc_txtUsername);
        txtUsername.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblPassword.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_lblPassword.gridx = 2;
        gbc_lblPassword.gridy = 4;
        panelTop.add(lblPassword, gbc_lblPassword);
        
        pwdPassword = new JPasswordField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_pwdPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_pwdPassword.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_pwdPassword.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_pwdPassword.gridx = 4;
        gbc_pwdPassword.gridy = 4;
        panelTop.add(pwdPassword, gbc_pwdPassword);
```

Can anyone provide me any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please show the source code generated by WindowBuilder.

Comment: Hey, it has been added @howlger

Comment: That's the code of the `panelTop` only. But to me it looks more like `panelTop` in `contentPane` not filling the whole space horizontally and vertically. Set a background color to `panelTop` to see whether I am guessing right or wrong.

Comment: I already tried that. It does take up the whole pane. I just changed from using gridbaglayout to miglayout. That seems to work for me.